# Emma unable to find CTL hence unable to do ForceDump

Tags: emma, ctl

I downloaded emma 2.1.5320 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/emma/files/emma-testing/2.1.5320/. Then did instrumentation for a jar file and started the application. Then tried to dump the coverage data by doing

```
 java -cp emma ctl -connect localhost:47653 -command coverage.get,coverage.ec -command coverage.reset
```

But got the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ctl    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ctl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: ctl. Program will exit.
```

I think for the version I am using, I should not be getting this exception. Please let me know how to get around this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Kiran